# Android add button to fragmentView from activity

Tags: java, android

I've created a simplified example of the problem i've encountered. What i want is add a button to my fragment view when clicking on another button in the fragmentview.

**Java**
MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}


public void addSubmitButton(View view){
    RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activityLayout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button tv1 = new Button(this);
    tv1.setText("Hello");
    tv1.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    rLayout.addView(tv1);
}
```

**XML** ActivityMain

```
<fragment 
   android:id="@+id/fragment"
   tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

**XML** fragment_main

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/activityLayout"
        tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">


        <Button               
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="addSubmitButton" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In the codes above I've removed not relevant code (like width height etc)

When i click the button onclick fires addSubmitButton, then the app crashes on a nullpointer for the line rLayout.addView(tv1); in addSubmitButton.

why is it null?

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: @sric_cac Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at nl.somename.someothername.MainActivity.addSubmitButton(MainActivity.java:62)

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is not the correct way.

First, add the proper definition in your fragment view declaration in your activity's layout

```
android:name="com.example.android.fragments.MainActivityFragment"
```

You'd have to use a Fragment Manager to find the fragment populated into your activity. Once you have this fragment, you can get its view, in your case the RelativeLayout and then add the desired Button to this view.

The following might help:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                fm.findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragmentId).getView().findViewById(R.id.activityLayout)
```

If you are using the support fragment use the getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: ive added :  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment).getView().findViewById(R.id.activityLayout);  Now i get a nullpointer on  RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment).getView().findViewById(R.id.activityLayout);

Comment: Could you please you check whether the null is on 'fm' or on the output of 'getView()' or on the output of 'findViewById()' ?

Comment: You using support support versions of Activity and Fragment ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with support support versions of Activity and Fragment ?  How can i check ?

Comment: I am sorry, the null is on getView(). getView will return the view set by onCreateView of the Fragment. Throwing null here because you have missed adding the fragment definition properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the fully qualified name in your fragment element:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.MyFragment"
          android:id="@+id/fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: it is there note (n the codes above I've removed not relevant code (like width height etc)) thought it would be not relevant enough ')